# sum all data-price from input with attribute available in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Im fighting with my code for a couple of hours, and no success.
I want to sum all values from data-price but I am constantly getting NaN.
My code "looks" correctly created, not understand why it do not work.
Any help will be appreciable.

```js
$("#sub").click(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('#form input').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price');
  });
  alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="make" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="got" value="" data-price='10'>
  <input type="hidden" name="get" value="" data-price='20'>
  <button id="sub">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: could be because the first input doesnt have a data-price. try checking if it exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the first input has no `data-price` attribute, therefore `undefined` is returned and causes an error in the calculation.

To fix this you can coerce a null/missing value to `0` before you add it to the `sum`:

```js
$("#sub").click(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('#form input').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0; // note the change on this line
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="make" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="got" value="" data-price='10'>
  <input type="hidden" name="get" value="" data-price='20'>
  <button id="sub">submit</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively you could put a class on only the desired `input` elements whose values you want to total and select by that instead.